Using QGIS with Docker Geoserver
To avoid misconfiguration, I'm using Geoserver Docker without any configuration except:

my workspace (name: myspace, url: myspace, defaultworkpace: true, isolated: true, services all checked, Grant access to any role: true)
my store (postgis db inside my docker, related to my workspace, expose PK: true, working fine)
my layer (a view from postgis, name: mylayer, enabled: true,SRS: 4326, Grant access to any role: true)

Then I try to connect QGIS to my geoserver but ain't got any answers to the getCapabilities call...
What I did in QGIS:
Create a new WMS Connexion
-> URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/myspace/ows
-> Auth: admin - geoserver
And then, nothing happen in QGIS.
In the logs of Geoserver (set to GEOSERVER_DEVELOPPER_LOGGIN) I can see that the GetCapabilities request from QGIS to geoserver is received:
26 Apr 14:45:08 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - Request: getServiceInfo
26 Apr 14:45:08 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - Request: getCapabilities
    AcceptLanguages = null
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Get = false
    Namespace = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetCapabilities, VERSION=1.3.0, SERVICE=WMS}
    Request = GetCapabilities
    RequestCharset = null
    RootLayerEnabled = null
    UpdateSequence = null
    Version = 1.3.0
26 Apr 14:45:08 DEBUG  [wms.capabilities] - producing a capabilities document for GetCapabilities [service: WMS, version: 1.3.0]

BUT, the fact is that the namespace should be myspace and not null.

Have you tried accessing the URL via your web browser?

Yeah, I'm developping a webmapping app and ain't got no issue to access to them through this one.

A docker instance may well be on a different port, check the response that QGis and your browser get and add them to the question. Next check the GeoServer log file and see if it has seen the request and if so what went wrong

@IanTurton I add the logs and for the docker ports it's still 8080.

what URL is QGIS actually sending the request to? check in the network debug plugin

Where do you find the network debug plugin for QGIS ? I searched in the extensions store but found nothing

It seems that the plugin Ian Turton is referring to, is deprecated. However, https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgisnetworklogger/ says that with QGIS >3.14 you can get this functionality with F12 (it is embedded in QGIS debug tools - hit the red 'record' button to put it in operation). Thanks @IanTurton for another great hint!

@GregStef I didn't knew this feature but good to know bc extremely useful ! So the req is send has expected to my localhost:8080/geoserver ! Should I replace the localhost by the name of my docker container or something ?

Assuming that 1) You run the Geoserver image in PC1 and 2) You have set the ports export correctly, opening a browser in PC1 and hitting localhost(perhaps with port)/geoserver will get you to the admin gui. Simmilarly, you get the capabilities xml. If those two are successful and you run QGIS in the same PC1, then it should work (I know it does, I have QGIS projects working with mixed sources local, remote and containerized).

Apparently the WMS seems to work now but for the WFS I get the following error message:
Downloading layer features failed or partially failed: WFS error report (code=NoApplicableCode text=java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0} boundedBy Failed to get property: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}boundedBy Exception occurred while computing reprojected boundsCannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes).
(I'm working with views that has pk and using 4326 as my project)
